# Javascript Date.getTime() format problems

Tags: javascript

Hi Guys Its just bugging me.

I have here two dates w/c are the same but in different formats.

```
var date1 = new Date('1985-04-15'); //April 04, 1985
var date2 = new Date('04/15/1985'); //April 04, 1985
```

now the problem is when converting this two to "time"

```
date1.getTime() would output 482371200000 //
date2.getTime() would output 482342400000 //
```

anyone could explain me why this two outputs different values? does the "/" or "-" affects how the date was converted to time?

Comment: one is in GMT("-"), one is in local time ("/").

Comment: so the slash and minus sign really does affect the whole output? thanks @dandavis

Comment: A terrific example of why you should not parse date strings with the Date constructor. Do it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plug the numbers back into the Date constructor to see what dates it's generating, like this:

```
new Date('1985-04-15').getTime();
482371200000
new Date('04/15/1985').getTime()
482335200000
new Date(482335200000)
Mon Apr 15 1985 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)
new Date(482371200000)
Mon Apr 15 1985 10:00:00 GMT+1000 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)
```

So for some reason in Chrome, the one with Slashes is getting set to the timezone plus (what I assume is) my time offset. I know this isn't the answer but I couldn't post it all in the comment section sorry.

Comment: yes its just really confusing why the two is different, as what @dandavis said, the slash and minus sign affects what date is generated.

Comment: There's a whole thing you can read about how Date.parse works, it is literally like you say: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse
see: Differences in assumed time-zone

Comment: I think I'd advise not passing in date strings like that if you can avoid it, I feel like I've seen cross browser issues when parsing free form date strings, especially if you have to work with older browsers.

Comment: I think the answer is that 2014-04-10 is considered to be the start of a ISO 8601 date string, which are parsed into UTC dates, whereas all other freeform strings are not, and are parsed into the local timezone. I suppose they overloaded it like that to keep the api smaller, or because they didn't think Date.fromISO8601String("2001-02-03") made for a very nice looking function name.

Comment: @DamonSmith—[according to ECMA-262](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2), an ISO string without a timezone is assumed to be UTC (but who reads the spec?). Parsing of any other string format is implementation dependent. Parsing of date and time strings in general using the Date constructor is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation is give here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

`new Date()` or `Date.parse()` assumes the timezone, if timezone is not specified in the input string. Assumption may be wrong for some string formats.

You can always get the UTC time using Date.UTC

```
var date1 = new Date('1985-04-15'); //April 04, 1985
var date2 = new Date('04/15/1985'); //April 04, 1985
```

Now instead of using `date1.getTime()` use `Date.UTC`

```
Date.UTC(date1.getFullYear(), date1.getMonth(), date1.getDate()) //482371200000
Date.UTC(date2.getFullYear(), date2.getMonth(), date2.getDate()) //482371200000
```